# GoogleAppEngine error: rdbms_mysqldb.py:74

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Trying to do HelloWorld on GoogleAppEngine, but getting the following error.

`C:\LearningGoogleAppEngine\HelloWorld>dev_appserver.py helloworld
WARNING  2012-07-17 10:21:37,250 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 133, in 
run_file(file, globals())`

`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 129, in run_file
execfile(script_path, globals_)`

`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 694, in  sys.exit(main(sys.argv))`

`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 582, in main root_path, {}, default_partition=default_partition)`

`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3217, in LoadAppConfig raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError`

I've found posts on GoogleCode, StackO regarding this issue. But no matter what I try, I still can't overcome this error.
Python version installed on Windows 7 machine is: 2.7.3
GAE Launcher splash screen displays the following:
Release 1.7.0
Api versions: ['1']
Python: 2.5.2
wxPython : 2.8.8.1(msw-unicode)

Can someone help?

Comment: "The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded"

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime needed to be set to "Python27" not just "Python" and threadsafe needed be set to false, here is my **app.yaml**

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*  
  script: helloworld.py
```

Here is my **helloworld.py**

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

Answer (score 1):

it's been a while, but I believe I've previously fixed this by adding `import rdbms` to dev_appserver.py

hmm.. or was that `import MySQLdb`? (more likely)

Comment: Tried both did not work. After fixing my app.yaml, the app fired up and was browsable. Yeah! But, still getting 2 warnings in the logs, about what I originally thought was the prob and, secondarily, a warning about, Could not initialize images API, will probably stack-flow a seperate question for these two warnings, in a bit. Thanks for stepping up.

Answer (score 0):

just had the exact same error messages: I found that restarting Windows fixed everything and I did not have to deviate from the YAML or py file given on the google helloworld python tutorial.